# Get group events as a system user with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website which should list all the events from my facebook group. So I created a facebook dev account and created an app.

When I tried to get the data with the graph API explorer it worked, but the access token expired after a few hours. So I had to get a never-expiring access token.

I created a sytem user at the facebook business manager. With the system user I got a never-expiring access token but I couldn't get the event data anymore. Everytime I tried it I got this response.

> "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"

I have the following permissions as system user:

> read_insights, read_audience_network_insights, manage_pages, pages_manage_cta, pages_show_list, publish_pages, business_management

Why did it fail? Are the permissions correct?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: there is no never-expiring token you can use for this. and why would you add all those permissions? all of them are for pages, not groups.

Comment: If there is no never-expiring token I can use, how should I get my facebook group events for my website? Do you have an idea?

Comment: did you read this? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/events - what token are you using exactly? a user token or a page token? or maybe an app token? you should add the relevant code in your question. also, make sure to select the correct app in the api explorer.